# Changing value of HTML doesnt correctly change the value?

Tags: javascript, dom

When I change the value of an element, the html inside changes however it doesnt get recognised as it still says field is required. I tried changing the elements required property to false but that didnt help either. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLiga.png)

```
let element = document.getElementById('mat-input-2')

element.focus()
element.value = "test@gmail.com"
element.required = false;
element.blur();
```

```
<input _ngcontent-sde-c17="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" data-test="email" formcontrolname="email" matinput="" placeholder="Email" type="email" id="mat-input-2" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" required="" aria-describedby="mat-error-3">
```

Answer (score 1):

`required` is a boolean attribute. If it is present in `HTML element`, doesn't matter it contains any value even the `false` value also, then it is considered as a `true` value. So you have to completely remove the `attribute`. You can use either [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) or [toggleAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute).

You can see the example of all three `setAttribute`, `removeAttribute`, and `toggleAttribute`

```js
const element = document.querySelector("input")
const btnSetAttribute = document.querySelector('#btnSetAttribute');
const btnRemoveAttribute = document.querySelector('#btnRemoveAttribute');
const btnToggleAttribute = document.querySelector('#btnToggleAttribute');

btnSetAttribute.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if( !element.disabled ){
        element.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else {
        element.setAttribute('disabled', false);
    }
})

btnRemoveAttribute.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if( !element.disabled ){
        element.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else {
        element.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
})

btnToggleAttribute.addEventListener('click', e => {
    element.toggleAttribute('disabled');
})
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="click button to disable"/>
<br />
<button id="btnSetAttribute"> disable using setAttribute </button>
<button id="btnRemoveAttribute"> disable using removeAttribute </button>
<button id="btnToggleAttribute"> disable using toggleAttribute </button>
```

You should use either `removeAttribute` or `toggleAttribute`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

let element = document.getElementById('mat-input-2')

element.focus()
element.value = "test@gmail.com"
element.toggleAttribute('required');
element.toggleAttribute('aria-required');
element.blur();
```

```html
<input _ngcontent-sde-c17="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" data-test="email" formcontrolname="email" matinput="" placeholder="Email" type="email" id="mat-input-2" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" required="" aria-describedby="mat-error-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

**To remove:**

```
element.removeAttribute('required');
element.setAttribute('aria-required', 'false');
```

**To add:**

```
element.setAttribute('required', '');
element.setAttribute('aria-required', 'true');
```

---

If you toggle `true`/`false` in required field repeatedly, it's better to make a function for that operation.

**Here is an example:**

```html
<input id="inputElem" type="text" aria-required="true" required>
```

```js
const inputElem = document.querySelector('#inputElem');

function toggleInputRequired(element, status = true) {
  if (status) {
    element.setAttribute('required', '');
    element.setAttribute('aria-required', 'true');
  } else {
    element.removeAttribute('required');
    element.setAttribute('aria-required', 'false');
  }
}

toggleInputRequired(inputElem, false); // Remove required
toggleInputRequired(inputElem); // Add required
```